# How to use the @Input() of a component as initial value for an input field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

If I have **Component A** that contains **Component B** is there a correct way to use the value of a `@Input()` property on **Component B**  as the initial value of an input field in that component?

An example of something I tried was to pass in the value when constructing the form. But it only works if it is declared again in `ngOnInit`.

Component A template:

```
<component-b [(initialValue)]='initialValue'><component-b/>
```

Component B:

```
@Input() initialValue!: string;
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    inputField: new FormControl(this.initialValue),
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    inputField: new FormControl(this.initialValue),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the main point of using ngOnInit instead of constructor.

at the moment of constructor execution the instance of a component is being created, but inputs are not bound yet. ngOnInit executes a bit later, when the inputs are bound already, but the template of a component itself isn't executed yet.

The correct result would be to remove form creation from the constructor, and leave the one in ngOnInit